# Laravel : using where clause with name contain space

Tags: laravel, where-clause

I have simple method to get id of username :

```
public function get_team($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username',$username)->first();
    return $user;
}
```

when I used it with names have space between them like (ahmed ali) it return no data.
I searched here and found many solution but not work

Comment: Your question is not clear. what are the usernames in the db and what is in $username when it fails?

Comment: @GertB. I changed the code may be more clear

Comment: No, what are the usernames  in the database? If 'ahmed ali' exists in the db, this should return the user model

Comment: `User::where('username', 'LIKE', "%$username%")->get();`

Comment: @JEJ "spaces between"

Comment: @GertB.  'ahmed ali' is found in database and when i send 'ahmed ali' to this function it is  return nothing

Comment: Your route method is get?

Comment: @sta yes it is get

Comment: @Sermedmayi if "ahmed ali" is in the database column username, it will be returned. I would check the $username var with `dd($username)`

Comment: Then use `urldecode($username)`

Comment: @sta ok, that makes sense. did not think of that because if you use the request object from Laravel, you don't need to decode it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On get request your url space convert to `%20` so `ahmed ali` will be `ahmed%20ali`, you need to decode or remove the `%20` from the url, you can use PHP's [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) method :

```
public function get_team($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', urldecode($username))->first();
    return $user;
}
```